# ASP.NET [How to get current Date from Windows and put into textbox]

Tags: asp.net

How to get current Date from Windows and put into my textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For just the date use:

```
someTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

For date and time use:

```
someTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

You might also want to look at the [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) formats available to you.